# что такое aria-current="page" в bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap

что такое aria-current="page" в bootstrap, обрыл весь интернет, но понятно нет нигде

Comment: https://www.aditus.io/aria/aria-current/#aria-current-page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все атрибуты, которые начинаются с `aria-` это атрибуты для [Accessible Rich Internet Applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA).

Они нужны для того, чтобы вашим сайтом было проще пользоваться людям с ограниченными возможностями. На них опирается браузер, у которого включены в настройках соответствующие опции и отрисовывает контент в более удобном для таких людей виде.

В данном случае атрибут `aria-current="page"` проставляется у тех ссылок, которые ведут на текущую страницу, на которой мы уже находимся (текущий активный пункт меню) на случай, если  стили отображения ссылок с классом .current или .active будут недостаточно очевидны.